# Headers is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send headers on a fetch call on my nodejs express api, but I'm getting headers is not defined when running this code

```
module.exports = saveSuverys = (url,user,password) => {
    let base64 = require('base-64');
    var myHeaders = new Headers();

myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic' + base64.encode(user + ":" + password));

fetch(url, {method:'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
       })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json =>  json);

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: where do you import `Headers` ?

Comment: also, where do you _define_ `headers` ? You have `myHeaders` not `headers`

Comment: edited it, that was not the issue, the headers not defined is refereing to new Headers()

Answer (score -1):

Change `headers.append(...);` to `myHeaders.append(...);`.

You're defining a variable named `myHeaders`, not `headers`.

Also, check if you're loading the module via require, like `const fetch = require('node-fetch');`.

Comment: edited it, that was not the issue, the headers not defined is refereing to new Headers()

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes I edited the answer, let me know if it solves your problem.